# Why doesn't [01-12] range work as expected?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use the range pattern `[01-12]` in regex to match two digit mm, but this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You're matching *characters*, not *character sequences*. Basically, you're matching against 0, 1 to 1, and 2 (ie. 0, 1 and 2). Consider this: `[a-z0-9]`, this matches all the lowercase letter, and all the digits, but only as a single character.

Comment: fwiw I created a javascript tool that creates a highly optimized regex from two inputs (min/max) https://github.com/jonschlinkert/to-regex-range

Comment: 0[1-9]|1[0-2]   ->   0|1|2 -> []s in a regex denote a character class. If no ranges are specified, it implicitly ors every character.

Comment: Do you need to match it with pure regex? If not, you can: 1.) just simply use the `\d+` pattern, 2.) convert the matched strings to numbers in your code. and then, 3.) check the number range like `if(num >= 0 && num <= 12){ /*do something*/ }`. It's so much faster and flexible.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood how character classes definition works in regex.

To match any of the strings `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, `05`, `06`, `07`, `08`, `09`, `10`, `11`, or `12`, something like this works:

```
0[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

  - [Numeric Ranges](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) (have many examples on matching strings interpreted as numeric ranges)

---

#### Explanation

A character class, by itself, attempts to match *one and exactly one* character from the input string. `[01-12]` actually defines `[012]`, a character class that matches one character from the input against any of the 3 characters `0`, `1`, or `2`.

The `-` range definition goes from `1` to `1`, which includes just `1`. On the other hand, something like `[1-9]` includes `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`.

Beginners often make the mistakes of defining things like `[this|that]`. This doesn't "work". This character definition defines `[this|a]`, i.e. it matches one character from the input against any of 6 characters in `t`, `h`, `i`, `s`, `|` or `a`. More than likely `(this|that)` is what is intended.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [Alternation with the vertical bar](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

---

#### How ranges are defined

So it's obvious now that a pattern like `between [24-48] hours` doesn't "work". The character class in this case is equivalent to `[248]`.

That is, `-` in a character class definition doesn't define numeric range in the pattern. Regex engines doesn't really "understand" numbers in the pattern, with the exception of finite repetition syntax (e.g. `a{3,5}` matches between 3 and 5 `a`).

Range definition instead uses ASCII/Unicode encoding of the characters to define ranges. The character `0` is encoded in ASCII as decimal 48; `9` is 57. Thus, the character definition `[0-9]` includes all character whose values are between decimal 48 and 57 in the encoding. Rather sensibly, by design these are the characters `0`, `1`, ..., `9`.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

---

#### Another example: A to Z

Let's take a look at another common character class definition `[a-zA-Z]`

In ASCII:

- `A` = 65, `Z` = 90
- `a` = 97, `z` = 122

This means that:

- `[a-zA-Z]` and `[A-Za-z]` are equivalent
- In most flavors, `[a-Z]` is likely to be an illegal character range

  - because `a` (97) is "greater than" than `Z` (90)
- `[A-z]` is legal, but also includes these six characters:

  - `[` (91), `\` (92), `]` (93), `^` (94), `_` (95), `` ` `` (96)

#### Related questions

- [is the regex [a-Z] valid and if yes then is it the same as [a-zA-Z]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658844/is-the-regex-a-z-valid-and-if-yes-then-is-it-the-same-as-a-za-z)

Comment: For me, I was looking for months without prefixing with 0 if single digit.
And I used this ([1-9]|(1[0-2])) and it works.

Comment: __Important to note:__ If you find this page wanting a solution for your number range that only has single digits before getting to the tens, `0[1-9]|1[0-2]` won't work. Changing it to the logical next step `[1-9]|1[0-2]` doesn't work either for understandable reasons (It matches the `1` only in `10`, `11`, and `12`). Had to use `\b(?:[0-9]|1[0-1])\b` to prevent that. `\b`'s makes sure regex matches word (or in this case number) boundaries (`^` & `$` didn't); brackets make the or (`|`) consider the other side of it; and finally `?:` is to not create a submatch with the use of the brackets.

Comment: @polygenelubricants : `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,17,18".match(/^(([1-9]|1[0-7])\,?)+$/g )` Can you please tell me why is this JS regex matches above 17?

Comment: @edam - polygenelubricants could, and so could I, but then we'd be **answering** a **questi**… wait… is this a *question* you are asking in a *comment*? There are *rulez* on this site ;) Ask a Question if you have a new question. Comments are only for critiquing and asking for clarification, and for responding to those.

Comment: @edam Oh, I see. You *did* re-ask it as a question an hour later. That's great! However, it would probably be a good idea to delete your comment here.

Answer (score 29):

A character class in regular expressions, denoted by the `[...]` syntax, specifies the rules to match *a single character* in the input. As such, everything you write between the brackets specify how to match *a single character*.

Your pattern, `[01-12]` is thus broken down as follows:

- 0 - match the single digit 0
- or, 1-1, match a single digit in the range of 1 through 1
- or, 2, match a single digit 2

So basically all you're matching is 0, 1 or 2.

In order to do the matching you want, matching two digits, ranging from 01-12 as numbers, you need to think about how they will look as text.

You have:

- 01-09 (ie. first digit is 0, second digit is 1-9)
- 10-12 (ie. first digit is 1, second digit is 0-2)

You will then have to write a regular expression for that, which can look like this:

```
  +-- a 0 followed by 1-9
  |
  |      +-- a 1 followed by 0-2
  |      |
<-+--> <-+-->
0[1-9]|1[0-2]
      ^
      |
      +-- vertical bar, this roughly means "OR" in this context
```

Note that trying to combine them in order to get a shorter expression will fail, by giving false positive matches for invalid input.

For instance, the pattern `[0-1][0-9]` would basically match the numbers 00-19, which is a bit more than what you want.

I tried finding a definite source for more information about character classes, but for now all I can give you is this [Google Query for Regex Character Classes](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=regular+expression+character+classes&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m7&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=). Hopefully you'll be able to find some more information there to help you.

Answer (score 10):

This also works:

`^([1-9]|[0-1][0-2])$`

`[1-9]` matches single digits between 1 and 9

`[0-1][0-2]` matches double digits between 10 and 12

There are some good examples [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: To be exact, `[0-1][0-2]` also matches `00`. That said, +1 for the link (which I've used in my answer).

Comment: `[0-1][0-2]` must be carefully interpreted, as it allows strings like `00`, `01`, and `02`, but it doesn't admit `03` up to `09`, admitting finally `10`, `11` and `12`.  A right regex for that is `[1-9]|1[0-2]`, or even `0*([1-9]|1[0-2])` (this last allowing any number of leading zeros).

Answer (score 2):

The `[]`s in a regex denote a **character class**.  If no ranges are specified, it implicitly *or*s every character within it together.  Thus, `[abcde]` is the same as `(a|b|c|d|e)`, except that it doesn't capture anything; it will match any one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, or `e`.  All a range indicates is a set of *characters*; `[ac-eg]` says "match any one of: `a`; any character between `c` and `e`; or `g`".  Thus, your match says "match any one of: `0`; any character between `1` and `1` (*i.e.*, just `1`); or `2`.

Your goal is evidently to specify a number range: any number between `01` and `12` written with two digits.  In this specific case, you can match it with `0[1-9]|1[0-2]`: either a `0` followed by any digit between `1` and `9`, or a `1` followed by any digit between `0` and `2`.  In general, you can transform any number range into a valid regex in a similar manner.  There may be a better option than regular expressions, however, or an existing function or module which can construct the regex for you.  It depends on your language.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
0?[1-9]|1[012]
```

- 07: valid
- 7: valid
- 0: not match
- 00 : not match
- 13 : not match
- 21 : not match

To test a pattern as 07/2018 use this:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/([2-9][0-9]{3})$/
```

(Date range between 01/2000 to 12/9999 )

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to do this but to get the third condition of only a 0 to pass.

Answer (score 0):

As polygenelubricants says yours would look for 0|1-1|2 rather than what you wish for, due to the fact that character classes (things in []) match characters rather than strings.

Comment: `0|1-1|2` - this notation is very misleading. Something like `0|1|2` would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to keep mm-yyyy is `^0*([1-9]|1[0-2])-(20[2-4][0-9])$`

Comment: Probably better `^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2)-…` (only a single optional leading 0 in the not double digit case)

Comment: True, single (`?`) is better than unlimited (`*`).