# Regex validity for Degree

Tags: regex

i have an assignment where i should check validity of the string where :

- N90 -> North and must have key degree between 0-90
- W180 -> have degree between 91-180
- S270 -> have degree between 181-270
- E360 -> have degree between 271-360

how can i create a reg ex like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression. This is a classic example of the kind of problem that regular expressions are not appropriate for. Just split the string into a direction (the first character) and a number, and check that the number meets the required conditions for the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Regex doesn't really understand numeric ranges, and must match these numbers as digit sequences, so it's not the best tool for the job. That said, this *can* be done, but it's going to be ugly

> `N90` -> North and must have key degree between 0-90

`N([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)`

> `W180` -> have degree between 91-180

`W(9[1-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)`

> `S270` -> have degree between 181-270

`S(18[1-9]|19[0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]|270)`

> `E360` -> have degree between 271-360

`E(27[1-9]|2[8-9][0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360)`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Numeric Ranges](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

#### Related questions

- [Regex: why doesn’t `[01-12]` range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected/)

Comment: Don't forget the anchors, or perhaps `\b` word boundaries.