# Trying to write a regex that matches only numbers,spaces,parentheses,+ and -

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regular that will check for numbers, spaces, parentheses, + and - 
this is what I have so far:

```
/\d|\s|\-|\)|\(|\+/g
```

but im getting this error: unmatched ) in regular expression
any suggestions will help. 
Thanks

Comment: @Christian Hayter - You edited out his problem. How are we supposed to answer it now? Please undo.

Comment: @Daniel: actually if you look at first revision, it's like that already. Christian didn't add the \ escapes. I'm also confused now what the question is about.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: it looks like there was a SNAFU somewhere; I've rolled back to the original.

Comment: @Borealid, @Daniel: so can anyone reproduce OP's problem when the pattern is `/\d|\s|\-|\)|\(|\+/g`? Because that looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm also confused... `/\d|\s|\-|\)|\(|\+/g` is in the original source, but Christian's revision shows it being changed *from* `/\d|\s|-|)|(|+/g` *to* `\d|\s|\-|\)|\(|\+/g`, when all he did was reformat the whitespace. Perhaps it's a bug in the SO revision code?

Comment: I think that the original code *was* `\d|\s|-|)|(|+/g`. For some reason, when it's formatted, the escapes appear to be put in?

Comment: @Daniel: let's get OP to confirm what's going on, then if there's a bug I can start a report on meta. I will also delete most of my comments here eventually, since it's just clutter once this matter is resolved.

Comment: All I did was add a newline and 3 spaces to change the formatting. Perhaps someone else tried to edit at the same time as me?

Answer (score 8):

Use a character class:

```
/[\d\s()+-]/g
```

This matches a single character if it's a digit `\d`, whitespace `\s`, literal `(`, literal `)`, literal `+` or literal `-`. Putting `-` last in a character class is an easy way to make it a literal `-`; otherwise it may become a range definition metacharacter (e.g. `[A-Z]`).

Generally speaking, instead of matching one character at a time as alternates (e.g. `a|e|i|o|u`), it's much more readable to use a character class instead (e.g. `[aeiou]`). It's more concise, more readable, and it naturally groups the characters together, so you can do e.g. `[aeiou]+` to match a sequence of vowels.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

---

#### Caveat

Beginners sometimes mistake character class to match `[a|e|i|o|u]`, or worse, `[this|that]`. This is wrong. A character class by itself matches one and exactly one character from the input.

#### Related questions

- [Regex: why doesn’t `[01-12]` range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awesome [Online Regular Expression Editor / Tester](http://rubular.com/)! Here is your [`[\d\s()+-]`](http://rubular.com/r/Vj18pNA9lo) there.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\d\s\(\)\-]+$/
```

This expression matches only digits, parentheses, white spaces, and minus signs.
example:

- 888-111-2222
- 888 111 2222
- 8881112222
- (888)111-2222
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your parenthesis, because parenthesis are used as special syntax in regular expressions:

instead of '(':
    `\(`

instead of ')':
    `\)`

Also, this won't work with '+' for the same reason:
    `\+`

Edit: you may want to use a character class instead of the 'or' notation with '|' because it is more readable:
    `[\s\d()+-]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[\d\s-+()]
```

Comment: Although `-` is placed directly after the short hand character class `\s` and therefor needs no escaping, I'd opt to put it (un-escaped) at the start or end of the character class to not cause confusion: 
`[-\d\s+()]` or `[\d\s+()-]`.