# Pattern matches an hyphen too

Tags: regex, perl

I have a piece of Perl code (pattern matching) like this,

```
$var = "<AT>this is an at command</AT>";

if ($var =~ /<AT>([\s\w]*)<\/AT>/i)
{
    print "Matched in AT command\n";
    print "$var\n\n";
}
```

It works fine, if the content inbetween tags are without an Hyphen. It is not working if a hyphen is inserted between the string present inbetween tags like this... `<AT>this is an at-command</AT>`.

Can any one fix this regex to match even if hyphen is also inserted ??

help me pls

Senthil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \S instead of \w.

```
if ($var =~ /<AT>([\s\S]*)<\/AT>/i) {
```

Answer (score 8):

#### On character class

Your pattern contains this subpattern:

```
[\s\w]*
```

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

`\s` is the shorthand for whitespace character class; `\w` for word character class. Neither contains the hyphen.

The `*` is the zero-or-more [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) specifier.

Now you should understand why this pattern does not match a hyphen: it matches zero-or-more of characters that is either a whitespace or a word character. If you want to match a hyphen, then you can include it into the character class.

```
[\s\w-]*
```

If you also want to include the period, question mark, and exclamation mark, for example, then you can simply add them in as well:

```
[\s\w.!?-]*
```

---

#### Special note on hyphen

**BE CAUTIOUS** when including the hyphen in a character class. It is used as a regex metacharacter in character class definition to define character range. For example,

```
[a-z]
```

matches one of any character the range between `'a'` and `'z'`, inclusive. By contrast,

```
[az-]
```

matches one of exactly 3 characters, `'a'`, `'z'`, and `'-'`. When you put `-` as the last element in a character class, it becomes a literal hyphen instead of range definition. You can also put it as the *first* element, or escape it (by preceding with backslash, which is the way you escape all other regex metacharacters too).

That is, the following 3 character class are identical:

```
[az-]         [-az]         [a\-z]
```

#### Related questions

- [Regex: why doesn't `[01-12]` range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)

Comment: Shouldn't `[a-\z]` be `[a\-z]`

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a hyphen in the char class as:

```
if ($var =~ /<AT>([\s\w-]*)<\/AT>/i)
```

Also since your regex has a `/` in it you can use a different delimiter, this way you can avoid escaping `/`:

```
if ($var =~m{<AT>([\s\w-]*)</AT>}i)
```

Comment: Thanks codaddict ... It works fine ... (i think i had properly accepted the answer ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have **everything** between  and  you can use

```
if ($var =~ /<AT>((?:(?!<AT>).)*)<\/AT>/i)
```

And it's ungreedy.

Comment: Your patter is in fact greedy, but it's forced to give back what it took to satisfy the match. If for instance the "</AT>" is followed by 10,000 "x"s the capture will match all 10,000, then give them up one by one until it gives up the "</AT>" and can then match the end of the pattern.
`/<AT>((?:(?!<\/AT>).)*)<\/AT>/i` or `/<AT>((?:(?!<\/?AT>).)*)<\/AT>/i` will prevent it from overmatching and then backtracking.
A more efficient way to write that is `/<AT>((?:[^<]*|<(?!\/?AT>))*)<\/AT>/`, it avoids testing the negative look ahead for each character that is about to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more characters to your class like [\s\w-]* (as codaddict told you).

Moreover, you should maybe use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the end of your command ("I want to match that only if it is followed by the ending statement") like :

```
if ($var =~ /<AT>([^<]*)(?=<\/AT>)/i)
```

[^<] stands for "any character (including hyphen) except "<".

You could even add a lookbehind :

```
if ($var =~ (?<=/<AT>)([^<]*)(?=<\/AT>)/i)
```

For more complexe things (since you seem to want a little parser), you should look at the theory of grammar and at lex/yacc.