# Creating a simple regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches words with the following condition:

- Match words which can contain characters like: æøå, and numbers.
- If a word contains any of the following characters, it is invalid:
  `+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \`

So for example these words are okay:

> testæøå
>   test12
>   12test

But these should fail:

> t+st
>   te&st

Comment: If utf-8 / character properties are available: `/^(\p{L}|[0-9])*$/` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: which language/tool are you using?

Comment: You don't need a regex for this (if you are using a programming language with a "string" type).

Comment: @LevLevitsky: You don't *need* a regular expression for *anything*, but this seems to be one of the tasks that regular expressions are well-suited to.

Comment: @Lev well my problem is that I have an input from an email subject field and need to pass it into a webservice which cant handle the characters, so I must first 'sanitize' the subject field and then pass it in

Comment: @ruakh What I mean is that the condition to be checked is not really a pattern; rather, a list of forbidden characters. Checking if a string contains any of characters from a set is not something I'd do with regex, because it doesn't win much here.

Comment: Yea, I see maybe I should just go the string manipulation route... since I'm no expert in regex.

Comment: +1 for "keeping an open mind" as advised in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you don't know, regex in C# is much slower than string manipulation:
[Regex in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex)
Yet, you can increase the speed if you optimize it using Regex.Compiled. This does cause your program to start up slower, however. If this is going to be any sort of web-based (C#/Silverlight), I highly recommend using String manipulation and searching over Regex, as it is going to be incredibly-slow for anyone using the page otherwise.

You can easily match Unicode or ASCII codes of characters and accept/deny words from there, with much better performance.

If you are determined to use regex, consider Perl, or other scripting languages, that are much faster with string manipulation using Regex.

Comment: Well you convinced me to abandon regex. I'll do this by good ol' string manipulation...

Comment: Best of luck! Adding those extra characters might make things a bit messy unless you create your own Verify class, or something :-P

Answer (score 1):

How about something like `[^+\-|!(){}\[\]\^"~*?:\\]+`.  This will match anything that does not contain the characters you want to exclude.  You'll have to check that I've backslashed the meta-characters rightly within the enclosing `[` and `]`

Comment: Almost... but it seem to match this word: "add-in" where it highlights add and in, but it contains a hyphen and so should not match "add-in"

Comment: Could you post the line(s) of code where you use the regex pattern?

Comment: Also to get it to recognize that `-` is part of the character class, perhaps this might work: `[^+|!(){}\[\]\^"~*?:\\-]+`.  Note that I put the hyphen last in the character class.  Should have thought of that before.

Comment: Take a look at these answers: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3529805/49251) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3521450/49251), which might help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm gonna go with Thumper, apparently there are no speed gain in using regex in c# =/

Comment: That's fine.  Although you were asking for regex, which is why I stuck to regex.

Comment: Yes, I did... I initially thought this would be the answer / the way to go upvoted you for your troubles