# regex remove digits and - in beginning

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm treating a list of strings, but I want to alter the strings so they don't look ugly to the user. An example list would be

```
2736162 Magazines
23-2311 Numbers
1-38122 Faces
5-231123 Newspapers
31-31235 Armynews
33-12331 Celebrities 1
33-22113 Celebrities 2
Cars
Glasses
```

And what I want is to trim out the beginning so that the ugly sequence of numbers and "-" are left out, and the user only sees the data that makes sense like:

```
Magazines
Numbers
Faces
Newspapers
Armynews
Celebrities 1
Celebrities 2
Cars
Glasses
```

How would I trim out the digits/-'s in the beginning with regex ?

**EDIT**
Would it be possible to design the same REGEX to also strip these values from:

```
FFKKA9101U- Aquatic Environmental Chemistry
FLVKB0381U- Clinical Drug Development
4761-F-Filosofisk kulturkritik
B22-1U-Dynamic biochemistry
```

to:

```
Aquatic Environmental Chemistry
Clinical Drug Development
Filosofisk kulturkritik
Dynamic biochemistry
```

the rule I would think of is that if there are only capital letters, digits and - or + signs before a - it only makes sense to the machine, and is not an actual word, and therefore should be stripped out, I don't know how to formulate this in regex though.

Comment: What flavor is this? You'd usually get better answers if you specify which flavor on regex questions.

Comment: @polygenelubricants - flavor? :D

Comment: C# regex is different from Java regex is different from Javacsript regex etc. In other words, I'm asking what programming language/tool context you're going to use this regex in. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you can match and replace `^[\d-]*\s*` with the empty string.

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `\d` is the shorthand for the digit character class, so `[\d-]` matches either a digit or a dash. The `\s` is the shorthand for the whitespace character class.

The `^` is the [beginning of the line anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). The `*` is "zero-or-more" [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Thus the pattern matches, at the beginning of a line, a sequence of digits or dash, followed by a sequence of whitespaces.

It's not clear from the question, but if the input is a multiline text (instead of applying the regex one line at a time), then you'd want to enable the [*multiline mode*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) as well.

---

#### C# snippet

Here's an example snippet in C#:

```
var text = @"
2736162 Magazines
23-2311 Numbers
1-38122 Faces
5-231123 Newspapers
31-31235 Armynews
33-12331 Celebrities 1
33-22113 Celebrities 2
Cars
Glasses
";

Console.WriteLine(
  Regex.Replace(
     text,
     @"^[\d-]*\s*",
     "",
     RegexOptions.Multiline
  )
);
```

The output is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Yn305)):

```
Magazines
Numbers
Faces
Newspapers
Armynews
Celebrities 1
Celebrities 2
Cars
Glasses
```

Depending on flavor, you may have to specify the multiline mode as a `/m` flag (or `(?m)` embedded). You may also have to double the backslash if you're representing the pattern as a string literal, e.g. in Java you can use `text.replaceAll("(?m)^[\\d-]*\\s*", "")`.

---

#### Special note on including dash in a character class

Do be careful when including the `-` inside a `[…]` character class, since it can signify a *range* instead of a literal `-` character. Something like `[a-z]` matches a lowercase letter. Something like `[az-]` matches either `'a'`, `'z'`, or `'-'`.

#### Related questions

- [Regex: why doesn't `[01-12]` range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)

Comment: thank you so much! Please have a look at my edit if you feel like it, I know you've already answered the question, so it's up to you to allow me to steal more of your expertise.

Comment: try looking at: http://ideone.com/SoVXM it get's the newest strings, but not the ones that just have digits in front of the name

Comment: @Jakob: so now you have two different patterns, so you can just "or" the pattern using alternation with `|`. I also modified the first pattern to use `\s+` instead of `\s*`. This seems to work with your current test: http://ideone.com/aqjyx

Comment: I looked it up in my encyclopedia - what you just did; it's the definition of AWESOME! thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If there are digits(with or without -'s) on every line you can just split the line on space, exclude first piece and then join again.