# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE digits and spaces in beginning

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have data of this pattern:

```
000000001 ItemA
000000002 ItemB
000000003 ItemC
```

and I want to get this result:

```
ItemA
ItemB
ItemC
```

I tried REGEXP_REPLACE with this regex: `@"^[\d-]*\s*"` that I found in the accepted answer of this: [regex remove digits and - in beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558578/regex-remove-digits-and-in-beginning) question like this:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(test_column, '@"^[\d-]*\s*"', '') FROM test_table;`

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution's code snippet is written in C# and utilizes [.NET Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions). However, the Oracle database requires [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)](https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_posix_extended_regular_expressions.htm) for compatibility with its [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302) function. To resolve this issue, you can use an Oracle POSIX-compliant regular expression, like the one below:

```
^[0-9]*[[:space:]]*
```

- `^` - It matches the beginning of the text being searched.
- `[0-9]` - It matches any single character that is a digit (0 to 9).
- `*` - It matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding character.
- `[[:space:]]` - It matches any white-space character, including spaces, tabs, and line breaks.
- `*` - It matches zero or more white-space characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, I didnt know there were many types of regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You have some small errors, but you can use folowing two queries

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ("data" varchar2(15))
;
```

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO table1 ("data")
         VALUES ('000000001 ItemA')
    INTO table1 ("data")
         VALUES ('000000002 ItemB')
    INTO table1 ("data")
         VALUES ('000000003 ItemC')
SELECT * FROM dual
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("data", '^[0-9-]*\s', '') FROM table1;
```

| REGEXP_REPLACE("DATA",'^[0-9-]*\S','') |
| --- |
| ItemA |
| ItemB |
| ItemC |

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("data", '^[[:digit:]-]*\s', '') FROM table1;
```

| REGEXP_REPLACE("DATA",'^[[:DIGIT:]-]*\S','') |
| --- |
| ItemA |
| ItemB |
| ItemC |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6gP0m8cE)

Comment: Thank you very much for the 2 variations.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be regular expression, try (fast!) `substr + instr` combination. For small data sets you won't notice any difference, but with A LOT of data, this should behave better.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '000000001 ItemA' from dual union all
  3     select '000000002 ItemB' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select substr(col, instr(col, ' ') + 1) result
  6  from test;

RESULT
---------------
ItemA
ItemB

SQL>
```

Comment: It has, but thank you very much, I will use it in other cases.