# Regular expression greater than and less than

Tags: asp.net, regex

This expression is to check number > 1

> ^[1-9]+[0-9]*$

- what is the expression to check if
  it's greater than a given value, say
  "99" ?
- what about a value less than, 99?

Update:

I'm using ASP.NET validation control.

Thanks.

Comment: "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

What is wrong with using `>`?

Comment: Was trying to do it with Regex. I think the built-in validation for asp.net helps get the job done faster.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected

Answer (score 6):

You say this is homework, so I'll give my answer for greater than 57 instead; you can take the idea and modify it.

```
/^([6-9][0-9]|5[89]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})$/
```

If you don't have the `{a,}` construct,

```
/^([6-9][0-9]|5[89]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]+)$/
```

Comment: The last char class should be [0-9]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Rowlf comment! You should not need a regex for doing this (unless this is an interview question :) ) . Just use '>'.

Well, your given regex `^[1-9]+[0-9]*$` is matches `>=1` not only `>1`