# Trouble with matching numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having issues with regex in PHP. Here is the code I am using the regex on:

`<br />Level 163 Operative </div>      <div class="sectionBar">`

This is the preg_match statement:

```
preg_match("/<br \/>Level ([0-300]) (.*) <\/div>      <div class=\"sectionBar\"><\/div>/i", $output, $op);
  $top = $op[1];
  echo "$top";
```

However, when I try this, it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) only matches a single character so you cannot use it for a range like `0-300`

Comment: **1st**, [please do NOT parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1519058)... **2nd**, Check [`THIS`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148251/1519058) for more information how character classes definition works... Then **finally**, check [`This too`](http://regex101.com/r/iV0xY0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a series of examples that should help you:

```
([1-3][0-9][0-9])
```

this will match 100-399, don't use [0-3] hoping to match below 100, as it'll only match numbers with a leading zero (055 but not 55)

```
([1-2]\d{2})
```

matches 100-299 (\d matches a single digit, same as [0-9])

```
([1-2]\d{2}|\d{2})
```

matches 10-299

```
([1-2]\d{2}|\d{2}|[1-9])
```

matches 1-299

```
([1-2]\d{2}|\d{2}|[1-9]|300)
```

matches 1-300

```
([1-2]?\d?\d|300)
```

1-300, more elegant way (making first 2 digits optional with ?)

```
([1-2]?\d?\d)
```

short version, matches 0-399

```
(\d{1-3})
```

shortest version, matches 0-999 (1-3 digits)

Comment: Shouldn't you include word boundary tokens, in order to eliminate matching parts of series of digits?

Comment: Actually, I see it is not necessary in the context of the complete regex posted initially, as there it is surrounded by spaces.

Comment: In what regex flavour `^d` matches a digit?

Comment: I thought it was just a typo or some peculiarity of whatever client that poster was using

Comment: Yeah was tired, should have been \d, edited it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that matches 0-300; allows leading zero's, and specifically excludes the number if it is preceded by a negation sign; or embedded within other numbers:

```
'/(?<!-)\b0*(?:300|[12][0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\b/'
```