# Can't find match with grep when I extend the regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, unix

(DISCLAIMER: This is a homework exercise)

I have a file with several registers, each of them has a credit card number. I have to retrieve those registers that belong to an AMEX card, which begin with 34, 35 or 36 and have 15 digits overal like this:

`XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX`

Separated by hyphens every 4 digits.

I tried using grep over that file to detect those numbers, but to no avail. This is the original command I used:

```
grep -E "[34-36][0-9]{2}[\-]([0-9]{4}[\-]){2}[0-9]{3}" MYFILE.txt
```

Which I assumed it would work, because I think the regular expression means:

"*A number between 34 and 36, followed by 2 numbers from 0 to 9, followed by a hyphen, followed by 4 numbers from 0 to 9 followed by a hyphen (this twice) followed by 3 numbers from 0 to 9*".

But this command retrieved nothing. For the record, I have this register:

`3435-9999-8765-333`

in the file, so I should at least retrieve that.

What's funny is that if I change the regular expression to just `[34-36][0-9]{2}`, I get a match (obviously), and if I add the hyphen (`[34-36][0-9]{2}[\-]`) I still get a match, ***but*** if I add anything after it (like `[34-36][0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]`, `[34-36][0-9]{2}[\-]a` while changing the record to have an "a" after the first two digits) I stop retrieving anything.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the hyphen in the regular expression? Which would be the right one?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `[34-36]` is correct, I think you'll need `(34|35|36)`. I don't use character classes to often; but I think they are a single character to another single character if it is a range, e.g. `a-z` or `0-9`, or a list of characters. Here's a thread on it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected.

Comment: or `3[4-6][0-9]....` recall that any list or range of characters (numbers) inside of `[ ...]` take one position of input. Good luck.

Comment: `[34-36]` means Any of (3, any number between 4 and 3, and 6). Regex flavors will usually trip on range out of order though `4-3`. While simple here because you only need three numbers, matching a range of numbers in regex can get to be quite the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
[3][4-6][0-9]{2}-([0-9]{4}-){2}[0-9]{3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should anchor the expression at the start of the line with the circumflex `^`. (if your lines start with the card number, otherwise delete the `^` from the expression) There is no need to escape the hyphen within the character class (e.g. `[\-]` should be `[-]`. With that, try:

```
grep -E "^3[4-6][0-9]{2}[-]([0-9]{4}[-]){2}[0-9]{3}" MYFILE.txt
```