# access series of numbers higher than 9 with [ ]

Tags: bash, numbers, series

I want to change files with sed for a series of numbered filemnames (more than 10).
0 - 9 I can easily access using `sed -i 's/old/new/g' myfile[0-9]` but this doesn't seem to work for numbers higher than 10. How can I do this instead? like `[0-50]`?

Comment: Character classes, by their nature, match single characters only.

Comment: ...possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected (not voting to close as dupe myself because, as a gold-badge for bash, any close vote I offered would be a dupehammer, and they're not *quite* identical, so I think it's fair that this be up for vote).

Comment: BTW, `sed -i` is not specified by POSIX, and actively nonportable between major platforms (its calling convention for the native version on OS X is different from the GNU version's usage). Consider using a different, POSIX-specified in-place editor such as `ex` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A character class, like `[0-9]` or `[a-f]`, matches a single character only, by definition. They don't match "numbers", per se -- even if the digits given are numeric, they're being viewed only as character codepoints, not numeric values. That's the same thing in `fnmatch()`-style patterns (used here by the shell) as they are in regular expressions.

---

If you want 0-50, with globbing behavior (matching only files that exist) that can be done by composing multiple character classes, like so:

```
shopt -s nullglob # if no files match, return empty result
files=( myfile[0-9] myfile[1-4][0-9] myfile5[0] )

# if list of files is nonzero, run sed:
(( ${#files[@]} )) && sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' "${files[@]}"
```

To explain how that works:

- `myfile[1-9]` matches 1-9 (if they exist)
- `myfile[1-4][0-9]` matches 10-49 (if they exist)
- `myfile5[0]` matches 50, if and only if it exists.

Putting the list of files into the array and checking the array's length makes sure you don't run `sed` without any filenames at all listed, which could happen otherwise because of `nullglob`. (Why use `nullglob` at all here? Because you don't want `myfile5[0]` being passed as a literal filename if no `myfile50` exists, which is the default behavior otherwise).

---

There are some additional extensions to the POSIX sh standard available as well:

If you don't care if files exist (and want to put contents on the command line even if they don't), you can use brace expansion:

```
sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' myfile{0..50}
```

Alternately, if you simply care about matching one-or-more numeric digits at the end of the filename, you can use extglobs:

```
shopt -s extglob
sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' myfile+([0-9])
```

Comment: I like the brace expansion. That's new to me. For the others, if you don't feel like extglob, nullglob, you can always use the standard `ls | grep | xargs` pattern. For the last one, a simple `/bin/ls myfile* | grep "myfile[0-9]" | xargs --no-run-if-empty -n 1 sed -i -e 's/old/new/g'` would do it. Which I admit looks much more complicated, but if you're like me and won't remember the shopts, is a good alternative.

Comment: @Mort, `ls | grep` is actively buggy / evil. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- it can be *made* safe with enough GNU extensions like `find -print0`, `grep -z -Z`, and `xargs -0`, but that's stuff you have to remember. :)

Comment: Nice answer/explanation.... one thing I've never understood about `sed` is why it doesn't allow certain `+` repetition quantifiers (eg. `[0-9]+`). Any idea what the reason behind that might be?

Comment: @Mort, ...take a look at how `xargs` deals with filenames with literal quotes and spaces, too.

Comment: @l'L'l, that's not actually a `sed` restriction there re: the filenames -- it's the shell doing the work of replacing the glob expression with the list of names, before it even invokes the program it's running such as `sed` at all. To explain what you're seeing, shell patterns are fnmatch-style globs, not regexes, which is why the syntax differs.

Comment: @l'L'l, ...see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs for a description of the relevant syntax.

Comment: @I'L'I `sed` can operate using both basic (default) and extended regular expressions (with the  `-r` option). In basic regular expressions, for `+` to be a quantifier, it must be escaped: `\+`. In extended, it does not. (I think that `+` is not strictly posix basic re, but it is commonly used and sed has it.)

Comment: @Mort, ...heh; I took that question to be about expressions in filenames, but indeed, it's not so clear.