# How to extract specific strings along with their corresponding numeric values?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have following column 'checks' in my data frame 'B'  which has input statments in different rows. These statements have a variable 'abc' , and corresponding to them there is a value entry as well. 
The entry done are manual and are not coherent for each entry. I have to extract just 'abc' and followed by its 'value'

```
< B$checks

    rows    Checks
    [1] there was no problem  reported measures abc-96 xyz 450 327bbb11869 xyz 113 aaa 4 poc 470 b 3 surveyor issue
    [2] abc(107 to 109) xyz 115 jbo xyz 104 optim
    [3] problemm with caller abc 95 19468 4g xyz 103 91960 1 Remarks new loc reqd is problem
    [4] abc_107 xyz 116 dor problem 
    [5] surevy done , no approximation issues abc 103 xyz 109 crux xyz 104 
    [6] ping test ok abc(86 rxlevel 84
    [7] field is clean , can be used to buiild the required set up abc-86 xyz 94 Digital DSL  No Building class Residential Building Type Multi
    [8] abc 89 xyz 99 so as the user has no problem , check ping test
```

Expected output

```
rows    Variable    Value
        [1] abc 96
        [2] abc 107
        [3] abc 95
        [4] abc 107
        [5] abc 103
        [6] abc 86
        [7] abc 86
        [8] abc 89
```

I tried the following using references under similar queries

usisng str_match

```
library(stringr)
m1 <- str_match(B$checks, "abc.*?([0-200.]{1,})")  # value is between 0 to 200
```

which yielded some thing like below

```
    row var value
1   abc-96 xyz 450  0
2   abc(10  10
3   abc 95 1    1
4   abc_10  10
5   abc 10  10
6   NA  NA
7   NA  NA
8   NA  NA
```

Then I tried the following

```
B$Checks <- gsub("-", " ", B$Checks)
B$Checks <- gsub("/", " ", B$Checks)
B$Checks <- gsub("_", " ", B$Checks)
B$Checks <- gsub(":", " ", B$Checks)
B$Checks <- gsub(")", " ", B$Checks)
B$Checks <- gsub("((((", " ", B$Checks)
B$Checks <- gsub(".*abc", "abc", B$Checks) 
B$Checks <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", B$Checks)
regexp <- "[[:digit:]]+"   
m <- str_extract(B$Checks, regexp) 
m <- as.data.frame(m)
```

and was able to get the "expected output",

But now I am looking for following

1) Simpler set of commands or way to extract the expected output

2) Get values which are represented as range e.g. I want the below input row

```
rows    Checks
[2] abc(107 to 109) xyz 115 jbo xyz 104 optim
```

as

output >

```
rows    Variable    Value1 Value2
 [2]     abc        107   109
```

Need the solution for 1) and 2) as am working on larger data sets with same patterns and lot of mixed Variable-Value combinations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sub(".*?(abc)\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1 \\2", B$Checks)`. Note that `[0-200]` is [a wrong way to match number ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected).

Comment: actually, `[0-200.]{1,}` doesn't check for values between 0 to 200 but an unlimited amount of characters amongst the values "0" "1" 2" "."

Comment: your 2nd part needs more cases to identify the pattern

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the solution

Comment: @rock321987 i actually have lots of rows which are similar to patterns listed in point 2) , is their any way I can extract numeric values by modifying the syntax in the solution given

Comment: @smokinjoe I understand the accepted solution worked better, right? If not, I will post my answer with necessary explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the digits, specifying that you want `abc` prior to the digits with lookbehind:

```
Value <- sub(".*(?<=abc)(\\D+)?(\\d*)\\D?.*", "\\2", str, perl=TRUE)
# Value
#[1] "96"  "107" "95"  "107" "103" "86"  "86"  "89"
```

You can then put the values in a `data.frame`:

```
B <- data.frame(Variable="abc", Value=as.numeric(Value))
head(B, 3)
#  Variable Value
#1      abc    96
#2      abc   107
#3      abc    95
```

---

**data**

```
str <- c("there was no problem  reported measures abc-96 xyz 450 327bbb11869 xyz 113 aaa 4 poc 470 b 3 surveyor issue", 
"abc(107 to 109) xyz 115 jio xyz 104 optim", "problemm with caller abc 95 19468 4g xyz 103 91960 1 Remarks new loc reqd is problem", 
"abc_107 xyz 116 dor problem", "surevy done , no approximation issues abc 103 xyz 109 crux xyz 104 ", 
"ping test ok abc(86 rxlevel 84", "field is clean , can be used to buiild the required set up abc-86 xyz 94 Digital DSL  No Building class Residential Building Type Multi", 
"abc 89 xyz 99 so as the user has no problem , check ping test")
```

Comment: @rock321987 you mean change `?` into `*`? I don't see the benefit. Else, using your pattern won't work so I don't really see what you mean actually

Comment: It entirely depends upon input of OP..  it _might_ be possible to have a string like this `abc--96`..
FYI, your regex will fail for input `abc-96`

Comment: @rock321987 indeed I based the regex on OP example, I'll modify it to take into account the possible lack of other characters

Comment: @rock321987 the patterns you put in your first comment will work in `sub` for `abc--96` but fail for all OP's examples (and a lot of others)

Comment: my regex is working as expected. check [here](https://regex101.com/r/fMl9TZ/1) on OPs test cases..

`(\\D+)?` is same as `(\\D*)` and `\\D?.*` isn't needed.. though both of these won't have any impact

Comment: @rock321987 your pattern may be correct "in general" but it does not work with capturing with `sub` in `R`: try `sub("abc\\D*(\\d+)", "\\1", "abc(107 to 109) xyz")`, it gives `"107 to 109) xyz"`

Comment: @rock321987 well having the pattern is good, getting the desired output is better... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using gsub() twice and magrittr for better readibility:

```
library(magrittr)

data.frame(
  Variable = "abc",
  Value = data %>%
    gsub(".*(abc.{6}).*", "\\1", .) %>%
    gsub("[^0-9]+(\\d+).*", "\\1", .)
)
  Variable Value
1      abc    96
2      abc   107
3      abc    95
4      abc   107
5      abc   103
6      abc    86
7      abc    86
8      abc    89
```

First we get extract abc and the next 6 characters after and then extract the first integer to appear.

**data**:

```
data <- c("there was no problem  reported measures abc-96 xyz 450 327bbb11869 xyz 113 aaa 4 poc 470 b 3 surveyor issue", 
"abc(107 to 109) xyz 115 jio xyz 104 optim", "problemm with caller abc 95 19468 4g xyz 103 91960 1 Remarks new loc reqd is problem", 
"abc_107 xyz 116 dor problem ", "surevy done , no approximation issues abc 103 xyz 109 crux xyz 104 ", 
"ping test ok abc(86 rxlevel 84", "field is clean , can be used to buiild the required set up abc-86 xyz 94 Digital DSL  No Building class Residential Building Type Multi", 
"abc 89 xyz 99 so as the user has no problem , check ping test"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr` for manipulating strings and `rebus` to write readable regex:

```
library(stringr)
library(rebus)
str_match(checks, pattern = capture("abc") %R% optional(or1(c(SPC, PUNCT))) %R% capture(one_or_more(DGT)))
```

**output:**

```
     [,1]      [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "abc-96"  "abc" "96" 
[2,] "abc(107" "abc" "107"
[3,] "abc 95"  "abc" "95" 
[4,] "abc_107" "abc" "107"
[5,] "abc 103" "abc" "103"
[6,] "abc(86"  "abc" "86" 
[7,] "abc-86"  "abc" "86" 
[8,] "abc 89"  "abc" "89"
```

**data:**

```
checks <- c("there was no problem  reported measures abc-96 xyz 450 327bbb11869 xyz 113 aaa 4 poc 470 b 3 surveyor issue", 
            "abc(107 to 109) xyz 115 jio xyz 104 optim", "problemm with caller abc 95 19468 4g xyz 103 91960 1 Remarks new loc reqd is problem", 
            "abc_107 xyz 116 dor problem", "surevy done , no approximation issues abc 103 xyz 109 crux xyz 104 ", 
            "ping test ok abc(86 rxlevel 84", "field is clean , can be used to buiild the required set up abc-86 xyz 94 Digital DSL  No Building class Residential Building Type Multi", 
            "abc 89 xyz 99 so as the user has no problem , check ping test")
```