# Unable to return 10 in possible regex

Tags: r, regex

I have cells with text with numbers in brackets such as (1).  I was given help with stripping out text and returning the number in brackets.

```
newdataframe<- data.frame(gsub("[^()0-9]","",as.matrix(UltraCodes)))
```

However, my numbers in brackets go up to 13 and I didn't realise that the above code doesn't cover that.  I think the above relates to regex and I've looked at answers on how to return double digits

[Why doesn't [01-12] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)

So I've various ways to return double digits which work.  Except I can't return 10 which still get returned as 1.

```
newdataframe<- data.frame(gsub("[^()^([1-9]|[0-1][0-2])$","",as.matrix(UltraCodes)))
```

newdataframe<- data.frame(gsub("[^()[1-9]|1[0-3]]","",as.matrix(UltraCodes)))

newdataframe<- data.frame(gsub("[^()[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]]","",as.matrix(UltraCodes)))

How do I get 10 to be selected?

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output too, so that we could clearly understand your question more.

Comment: Please give examples of data you want to replace.

Comment: Is it an option to select the parenthesis and number 1 - 13 instead of removing the opposite? [`\((?:[1-9]|1[0-3])\)`](https://regex101.com/r/REkm9Q/1)

Answer (score 1):

To capture **up to 2 digits** number enclosed in brackets use this regular expression

```
(\([\d]{1,2}\))
```

For capturing as many as possible digits number enclosed by brackets, use this

```
(\([\d]+\))
```