# Regex - Best way to match all values between two two digit numbers?

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I want a Regex expression that will only match numbers between 18 and 31.  What is the right way to do this?

I have a set of strings that look like this:

```
"quiz.18.player.total_score" 
"quiz.19.player.total_score" 
"quiz.20.player.total_score" 
"quiz.21.player.total_score"
```

I am trying to match only the strings that contain the numbers 18-31, and am currently trying something like this

```
(quiz.)[1-3]{1}[1-9]{1}.player.total_score
```

This obviously won't work because it will actually match all numbers between 11-39.  What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't \[01-12\] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex**: [`1[89]|2\d|3[01]`](https://regex101.com/r/YPQWst/1)

For matching add additional text and escape the dots:

`quiz\.(?:1[89]|2\d|3[01])\.player\.total_score`

**Details**:

- `(?:)` non-capturing group
- `[]` match a single character present in the list
- `|` or
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `\.` dot
- `.` **matches any character**

Comment: Ah! This is great.  Can you explain why you used a non-capturing group?

Comment: @Parseltongue I guess it's not strictly necessary, but should be more efficient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do basically, you're using the grouping operator `()` only incidentally and not actually trying to group, just trying to combine some patterns with `|`. So you can deactivate the grouping logic with `?:`

Answer (score 2):

**!)** If `s` is the character vector read the fields into a data frame picking off the second field and check whether it is in the desired range.  Put the result in logical vector `ok` and get those elements from `s`.  This uses no regular expressions and only base R.

```
digits <- read.table(text = s, sep = ".")$V2
s[digits %in% 18:31]
```

**2)** Another approach based on the pattern `"\\D"` matching any non-digit is to remove all such characters and then check if what is left is in the desired range:

```
digits <- gsub("\\D", "", s)
s[digits %in% 18:31]
```

**2a)** In the development version of R (to be 3.6.0) we could alternately use the new `whitespace` argument of `trimws` like this:

```
digits <- trimws(s, whitespace = "\\D")
s[digits %in% 18:31]
```

**3)** Another alternative is to simply construct the boundary strings and compare `s` to them. This will work only if all the number parts in `s` are exactly the same number of digits (which for the sample shown in the question is the case).

```
ok <- s >= "quiz.18.player.total_score" & s <= "quiz.31.player.total_score"
s[ok]
```

Comment: Neat, but why the `as.is`?

Comment: This is very clever.  I'll have to approve the Regex solution, but this is good to know.

Comment: @thelatemail, I tend to use it routinely but you are right we don't need it here.  Have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using character ranges and alternations. For your range

```
3[10]|[2][0-9]|1[8-9]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNckI0/1/)