# Regex to match less than a two-digit number

Tags: regex

I have some records as such, in a file:

```
A 20 year old programmer
A 52 year old politician
A 12 year old practitioner
Many many more of these...
```

I want to match only lines that contain a number less than `20`. I have tried:

```
^[0-20]{2}$
```

But it works for only numbers `0-2`. How should I construct a regular expression to match numbers `< 20`? For instance, it should match:

```
A 12 year old practitioner
```

But not

```
A 20 year old programmer
A 52 year old politician
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\b1?[0-9]\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFQFei/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:1?[0-9])` - an optional `1` and any digit after it
- `\b` - a word boundary

**Word boundary variations**

To match anywhere in a string, even if glued to a word:

```
(?<!\d)1?[0-9](?!\d)
```

To  only match in between whitespaces:

```
(?<!\S)1?[0-9](?!\S)
```

Comment: That "glued to a word" one is exactly what I want, thanks so much! I'll accept this when the grace period ends.

Comment: @JackBashford Great. Note that in case you want to also match `00` you need to replace `1?` with `[01]?`

Comment: Ahh, because that would "optionally match a `0` or a `1`"?

Comment: @JackBashford `[01]` is a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching any single char defined inside the class, and `?` is a greedy quantifier matching the quantified pattern 1 or 0 times.

Comment: @JackBashford Also, see [Why doesn't \[01-12\] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex to match digit ranges is usually a bit clumsy, but here, you can do it pretty simply with:

```
\b1?\d\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/YCWmNo/2

In plain language: an optional one, followed by a digit. So, any standalone digit is allowed, but a two-digit number needs its first digit to be a 1.

If you want to permit leading zeros, change to `\b[01]?\d\b`.