# RegexIterator to match against filepaths

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I am writing a function to recursively traverse directories and return the files in them. The directories store call recordings within filepaths that follow the naming convention `'YY/mm/dd'`.

An example filepath will look like so `/vhosts/example.org/private/recordings/2018/11/21/user@example.org_XXXXXXXXX`

My script is supposed to traverse all the possible filepaths for a given time period and then iterate through the results filtering out the ones that match a certain person. Since the files are stored in this manner I am not using `filemtime()` instead I am building a regular expression to match against the filepath of the recording.

```
//make the date into a regular expression blocks
//this is only a small abstract of the logic that builds the regular expression
$year = date_format($start_date, 'Y');
$months = '([' . date_format($start_date, 'm') . '-' . date_format($end_date, 'm') . '])';
$days = '([' . date_format($start_date, 'd') . '-' . date_format($end_date, 'd') . '])';


//lets assume this was the regex built by that logic
$regex = preg_quote("2018/11/21");


//traverse and build the iterator
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root_directory);
$results = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

if($condition){
   $results = new RegexIterator($results, "#$regex*#", RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
}
```

**My question is does the RegexIterator match against the filename or filepath or both?** Without entering the if statement I get this response. When I enter the if statement I get an empty object. I haven't implemented the check for a particular user yet, I am first making sure I can narrow the time period accordingly.

```
object(SplFileInfo)#9 (2) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(112) "/vhosts/example.org/private/recordings/2018/11/21/user@example.org_82342342.wav"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(61) "user@example.org_82342342.wav"
}
```

Comment: Can you show what `$regex` contains - just to validate if it's reasonable.

Comment: yes I should have included that, I just added it.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected - this may be part of your problem.

Comment: yeah I looked into that that is why I put the disclaimer at the bottom of the question let me update the question so its clear what I am looking help with.