# python regex gives 1 instead of 01

Tags: python, regex

Taken reference [Why doesn't [01-12] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)

```
 m = re.search(r"(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]", DUNESX[01:44])
```

or

```
m = re.search(r"(\w+)\[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9])\:([0-9]+)\]", DUNESX[01:44])
```

or

```
m = re.search(r"(\w+)\[(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9])\:([0-9]+)\]", DUNESX[01:44])
```

or

```
m = re.search(r"(\w+)\[([0-1][0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]", DUNESX[01:44])
```

But output from above expressions are

```
['DUNESX1', 'DUNESX2', 'DUNESX3', 'DUNESX4', 'DUNESX5', 'DUNESX6', 'DUNESX7', 'DUNESX8', 'DUNESX9', 'DUNESX10', 'DUNESX11', 'DUNESX12', 'DUNESX13', 'DUNESX14', 'DUNESX15', 'DUNESX16', 'DUNESX17', 'DUNESX18', 'DUNESX19', 'DUNESX20', 'DUNESX21', 'DUNESX22', 'DUNESX23', 'DUNESX24', 'DUNESX25', 'DUNESX26', 'DUNESX27', 'DUNESX28', 'DUNESX29', 'DUNESX30', 'DUNESX31', 'DUNESX32', 'DUNESX33', 'DUNESX34', 'DUNESX35', 'DUNESX36', 'DUNESX37', 'DUNESX38', 'DUNESX39', 'DUNESX40', 'DUNESX41', 'DUNESX42', 'DUNESX43', 'DUNESX44']
```

Doesn't provide desired output like

```
['DUNESX01', 'DUNESX02', 'DUNESX03', 'DUNESX04', 'DUNESX05', 'DUNESX06', 'DUNESX07', 'DUNESX08', 'DUNESX09', 'DUNESX10', 'DUNESX11', 'DUNESX12', 'DUNESX13', 'DUNESX14', 'DUNESX15', 'DUNESX16', 'DUNESX17', 'DUNESX18', 'DUNESX19', 'DUNESX20', 'DUNESX21', 'DUNESX22', 'DUNESX23', 'DUNESX24', 'DUNESX25', 'DUNESX26', 'DUNESX27', 'DUNESX28', 'DUNESX29', 'DUNESX30', 'DUNESX31', 'DUNESX32', 'DUNESX33', 'DUNESX34', 'DUNESX35', 'DUNESX36', 'DUNESX37', 'DUNESX38', 'DUNESX39', 'DUNESX40', 'DUNESX41', 'DUNESX42', 'DUNESX43', 'DUNESX44']
```

Complete code is

```
import re 

group_list = ['DUNESX[01:44]']
host_list = getgrandchild(group_list)

def getgrandchild(child):
    nodelist = []
    if child is None:
        return
    for nodes in child:
        print(nodes)
        if re.match(r".*(\[[0-1][0-9]+\:[0-9]+\])", nodes):
            m = re.search(r"(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]", nodes)
            lb = int(m.group(2))
            ub = int(m.group(3))
            for i in range(lb, ub+1):
                nodelist.append(m.group(1)+str(i))
        elif re.match(r"(\w+)", nodes):
            m = re.search(r"(\w+)", nodes)
            nodelist.append(m.group(1))
```

Comment: What is DUNESX[01:44]???

Comment: gst = ['DUNESX[01:44]']
host_list = getgrandchild(gst)
def getgrandchild(child):
    nodelist = []
    if child is None:
        return
    for nodes in child:
        print(nodes)
        if re.match(r".*(\[[0-1][0-9]+\:[0-9]+\])", nodes):
            m = re.search(r"(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]", nodes)
            lb = int(m.group(2))
            ub = int(m.group(3))
            for i in range(lb, ub+1):
                nodelist.append(m.group(1)+str(i))
        elif re.match(r"(\w+)", nodes):
            m = re.search(r"(\w+)", nodes)
            nodelist.append(m.group(1))

Comment: Could you edit your qeustion with that code added pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. Here is a code that helps:

```
def getgrandchild(child):
    nodelist = []
    for nodes in child:
        m = re.search("(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]",nodes)
        for i in range(int(m.group(2)),int(m.group(3))+1):
            nodelist.append(m.group(1)+str(i).zfill(len(m.group(2))))
    return nodelist
```

You can see i've skipped some steps, but you can have them. I've focused on the main part.
We use `zfill` to add numbers of the form `'001'` or `'01'`, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3371180/13062813).
So, for this code, if you give:

```
getgrandchild(['DUNESX[01:44]'])
```

you get:

```
['DUNESX01', 'DUNESX02', 'DUNESX03', 'DUNESX04', 'DUNESX05', 'DUNESX06', 'DUNESX07', 'DUNESX08', 'DUNESX09', 'DUNESX10', 'DUNESX11', 'DUNESX12', 'DUNESX13', 'DUNESX14', 'DUNESX15', 'DUNESX16', 'DUNESX17', 'DUNESX18', 'DUNESX19', 'DUNESX20', 'DUNESX21', 'DUNESX22', 'DUNESX23', 'DUNESX24', 'DUNESX25', 'DUNESX26', 'DUNESX27', 'DUNESX28', 'DUNESX29', 'DUNESX30', 'DUNESX31', 'DUNESX32', 'DUNESX33', 'DUNESX34', 'DUNESX35', 'DUNESX36', 'DUNESX37', 'DUNESX38', 'DUNESX39', 'DUNESX40', 'DUNESX41', 'DUNESX42', 'DUNESX43', 'DUNESX44']
```

Also, if you give:

```
getgrandchild(['PYTHON[001:025]'])
```

you get:

```
['PYTHON001', 'PYTHON002', 'PYTHON003', 'PYTHON004', 'PYTHON005', 'PYTHON006', 'PYTHON007', 'PYTHON008', 'PYTHON009', 'PYTHON010', 'PYTHON011', 'PYTHON012', 'PYTHON013', 'PYTHON014', 'PYTHON015', 'PYTHON016', 'PYTHON017', 'PYTHON018', 'PYTHON019', 'PYTHON020', 'PYTHON021', 'PYTHON022', 'PYTHON023', 'PYTHON024', 'PYTHON025']
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua , for quickly figuring out & providing best solution .Appreciate your endeavors .Finally this is not regex issue ,the issue is with interpretation of '0' on left side of digits .