# How do I simplify that regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a remaining time data from a text but the times are written as months, weeks, days or hours rather then number. I've written this regex but it's a bit complicated. How can I simplify it?

```
[0-99] month[s]?|[0-99] week[s]?|[0-99] day[s]?|[0-99] hour[s]?
```

Example output:

```
2 days 4 hours
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

`[0-99]` is equivalent to a character set from 0 to 9, plus the character 9 - so it's equivalent to `[0-9]` - which is (often) equivalent to `\d`.

A character set with a single character in it is superfluous - just use the single character.

Finally, since the only thing that changes between the alternations is the word, put a group around the word and alternate inside the group:

```
\d (?:month|week|day|hour)s?\d
```

That's equivalent to your original pattern. But it sounds like you might be wanting to match up to 2 digits instead, in which case you can tweak it to:

```
\d{1,2} (?:month|week|day|hour)s?\d{1,2}
```

Comment: Thanks solved the problem