# regex [A-z] behaivour in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I thought [x-y] matches all characters from ascii code of x to ascii code of y. So, [A-z] should be any characters from 65 to 122. But grep in bash says 'Invalid range' and [a-Z] is correct for all alphabets, which in range from 97 to 90 in ascii code.

How exactly behaves in grep in such a case? And generally, [x-y] is nothing to do with ascii code in regexp?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658844/is-the-regular-expression-a-z-valid-and-if-yes-then-is-it-the-same-as-a-za-z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex(5) doesn't say anything abt the implementation. `[a-Z]` can be interpreted in other ways too (see joe's comment) `(122-65+1)= 58 != 26*2` => There are other chars you would be including IF someone implemented `[a-Z]` the way you wanted.

Anyway, bottom line is grep doesn't allow it, regex(5) doesn't enforce it.

So just use `[a-zA-Z]`.