# Regular Expression Not Working in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am doing a Find & Replace in Notepad++.  Each of the pieces work correctly, but when I put the entire string together, it is not working.

I have an old HTML document I am editing where the original page cut up the text, thus:

```
<div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>This is a line of[CR][LF]
    text that was cut to[CR][LF]
    fit on screen.</p>
</div>
```

I want to find the line breaks that are cutting up the text and eliminate them, but not other line breaks.

My regular expression is:

```
([A-z0-9]+)[\r\n][ ]{3,}([A-z0-9]+)
```

It will be replaced with:

```
$1 $2
```

I have tried each of the pieces of my regular expression and they all find what I would expect:  `([A-z0-9]+)` finds text, `[\r\n]` is finding my line breaks, `[ ]{3,}` is finding their initial indents, and `([A-z0-9]+)` again finds text.

I have even tried sets of expressions and they all work:  `([A-z0-9]+)[\r\n]` is finding text at the end of a line, `[\r\n][ ]{3,}` is finding line breaks with the indent at the beginning of the new line, and `[ ]{3,}([A-z0-9]+)` is finding initial indents followed by text.

Perhaps I have two questions:
1) Is this a Notepad++ bug, or have I missed something with my regular expression?
2) Any ideas on solving this by some other expression?

If it is a bug, I suppose I can just trial and error until something works.  It would probably be well to report the bug, though, so if anyone can verify that, it would help.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match your sample text. Also, don't use `[A-z]` because it accepts more character than letters. Prefer `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: I'd emphasize it more strongly than that: `[A-z]` does *not* mean `[A-Za-z]` Don't use it.

Comment: I edited my sample text, not sure if that is what you meant.  What additional characters are accepted by `[A-z]`?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658844/is-the-regular-expression-a-z-valid-and-if-yes-then-is-it-the-same-as-a-za-z

Comment: Your regular expression and the accepted answer are both like `[A-Za-z0-9]+)important characters([A-Za-z0-9]+)`. The two `[A-Za-z0-9]+` sections are overkill, the `+` can be omitted from both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex:

```
([A-z0-9]+)[\r\n][ ]{3,}([A-z0-9]+)
```

matches one of `\r` OR `\n`.

Use this:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)[\r\n]+[ ]{3,}([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

or

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)\R+[ ]{3,}([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Comment: I think that was it, thank you.  I used `([A-Za-z0-9]+)\r\n[ ]{3,}([A-Za-z0-9]+)`.  Does that seem like another proper solution to you?  I am not familiar with `\R`, what is that?

Comment: @Thomas: `\R` stands for any of `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.